# intellij and the concept of change lists

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-15, changelist

[change lists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/changelist.html) can someone explain to me in an easy manner:

why would I use change lists?

my basic question behind that is: is the idea of change lists to implement a feature and then keep it in the change list, and continue working without it? i dont think that is possible at all.

is it e.g. possible to change file A.php, add the changes to change list A1. Then add more changes to file A.php, and add those changes to change list A2. Can I then just commit A2, that contains the changes from A2, but not A1? is it possible to deactivate a change list? e.g. activating change list A2 means that the changes from A1 disappear, and I have locally only what is in A2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change lists are file specific. So if you're working on files A, B, and C in one change list, all changes to those files will be applied in that change list.

You can shelve a changelist and then work on any of those files without affecting the work you did in the shelf.

I usually use change lists to keep track of which issue/bug/feature I'm working on and try to avoid making changes to any file that spans more than one issue at a time.

Comment: bonus question: a change list is bound to a branch I guess? is it somehow possible that once you realize you are on the wrong branch, to move change lists to a different one?

Comment: You can create a patch file from a change list and apply that to another branch.